# Meaning of regular expressions like - \\d , \\D, ^ , $ etc

Tags: regex, r, gsub, stringr

What do these expressions mean? Where can I learn about their usage?

```
\\d 
\\D 
\\s 
\\S 
\\w 
\\W
\\t 
\\n 
^   
$   
\   
|  etc..
```

I need to use the `stringr` package and i have absolutely no idea how to use these .

Comment: We usually expect some code question, along with effort and data and desired output. You can have a look to `?regexp`,  http://regexr.com/, http://regexone.com/, Google, etc.

Comment: From within R enter this `?regex` to get information on regular expressions.  There are also links to tutorials and other information near the bottom of this page: https://code.google.com/archive/p/gsubfn/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From `?regexp`, in the *Extended Regular Expressions* section:

> The caret ‘^’ and the dollar sign ‘$’ are metacharacters that
>        respectively match the empty string at the beginning and end of a
>        line.  The symbols ‘\<’ and ‘>’ match the empty string at the
>        beginning and end of a word.  The symbol ‘\b’ matches the empty
>        string at either edge of a word, and ‘\B’ matches the empty string
>        provided it is not at an edge of a word.  (The interpretation of
>        ‘word’ depends on the locale and implementation: these are all
>        extensions.)

From *Perl-like Regular Expressions*:

> The escape sequences ‘\d’, ‘\s’ and ‘\w’ represent any decimal
>        digit, space character and ‘word’ character (letter, digit or
>        underscore in the current locale: in UTF-8 mode only ASCII letters
>        and digits are considered) respectively, and their upper-case
>        versions represent their negation.  Vertical tab was not regarded
>        as a space character in a ‘C’ locale before PCRE 8.34 (included in
>        R 3.0.3).  Sequences ‘\h’, ‘\v’, ‘\H’ and ‘\V’ match horizontal
>        and vertical space or the negation.  (In UTF-8 mode, these do
>        match non-ASCII Unicode code points.)

Note that backslashes usually need to be doubled/protected in R input, e.g. you would use `"\\h"` to match horizontal space.

From `?Quotes`:

> Backslash is used to start an escape sequence inside character
>   constants. Escaping a character not in the following table is an
>   error.
>   \n     newline
>   \r     carriage return
>   \t     tab

As others comment above, you may need a little more help if you're getting started with regular expressions for the first time. This is a little bit off-topic for StackOverflow (links to off-site resources), but there are some links to regular expression resources at the bottom of the [gsubfn package overview](https://code.google.com/archive/p/gsubfn/). Or Google "regular expression tutorial" ...

Comment: `\n` and `\t` are described in the "Character constants" section of the `?Quotes` help page.

Comment: @RichieCotton, feel free to edit if you like.  (Should this answer be made community wiki?)